# Marketo checkbox custom ques answers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, marketo

I am working with marketo and trying to import leads (registrations) from Marketo, Can anybody tell me What values are received when marketo custom checkbox question is checked/un-checked.

In my case I am getting 1 when checkbox (marketo checkbox) is selected and nothing when un-checked.

Please what values are received ?